# What other problems does hot desking solve?

Tags: work-environment, offices, office-layout

Senior management at my company are talking about possibly introducing hot desking<sup>*</sup>, which might be introduced at the same time as an office move planned in a few months. The new location will be large enough to accommodate the company size; there will be enough desks for everyone, space is not a problem.

What problems does hot desking strive to solve, apart from not having enough desks?

Does it actually solve those problems?

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_desking): *"Hot desking is an office organization system which involves multiple workers using a single physical work station or surface during different time periods. The "desk" in the name refers to an office desk being shared by multiple office workers on different shifts as opposed to each staff member having their own personal desk."*</sub>

---

*Update*

Etiquette is: I select only one answer, but several answers here answer this question; there are several other excellent answers.

Comment: Why do you think hot-desking strives to solve any problem apart from space utilization?

Comment: Does senior management plan to also participate in hot desking?  If they are or are not participants affects the how quickly "problems" are solved.

Comment: I think *desk sharing* is a more common term (Maybe 'regional'? I've never heard of *hot desking*) and understandable without having to look it up.

Comment: @JanDoggen To be fair, it's a fairly well-established term in the English-speaking working world. I've never heard of "desk sharing" so this may be a term specific to your locale, and perhaps others with which I am not familiar :)

Comment: Given the consensus on your question is "Only a few very specific situations, other than space utilization (which you say is a non-problem in your company)", you may want to rephrase the question "What is the impact (pros and cons) of hot desking?"

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Hot Desking is useful if team structure changes often, or if people are working from home for the majority of their time and their presence days can be coordinated company-wide. That's a lot of *if*s.

I've seen exactly one working example for each of these:

- one customer building test and measurement equipment organizes work items as short-lived projects, where they build teams with domain experts for each of the layers in their software stack (UI, remote control, settings data model, measurement data processing, hardware control). Each is chosen from a pool, and the team works together for a few weeks. Desks are allocated for the project duration, then switched around.
- one customer has 80% home office as standard. Each team meets once per week in the office to coordinate and review. Desks are allocated to the team for this one day. Company laptops are standardized, and docking stations are provided on each desk, so people bring in their laptop only, no cables or accessories.

I've also seen it fail miserably in an environment where 50 people shared 40 desks. Basically, people showed up at 7 AM to get one of the free desks, then tried to stay awake using lots of coffee.

Comment: So what happened to the last 10 people who didn't get a free desk?  "I guess you are working from home today, sorry about the wasted commute"?  How does that last beyond day 1?

Comment: @Myles, they usually usurped some conference rooms or space in the cafeteria, which was not good for productivity either.

Comment: Why would making your employees physically compete for a space to do their work seem like a good idea to *anyone*?

Comment: @GreySage: Because it reduces quantifiable costs by trading them for unquantifiable ones. The cost savings of less space and fewer desks is easy to pin a number on; the productivity loss, not so much. If your job is to make the numbers look good, but you don't understand people, you'll inevitably optimize your job into "focus on the quantifiables, and screw the rest".

Comment: @SimonRichter I can't even imagine how that would make it past the idea stage.  "Now hear me out, if we just use our meeting rooms as offices then we need less actual office space..."

Comment: @Myles don't give them any ideas.  I'm sure someone right now is thinking, yeah, that's a good idea.

Comment: @Myles What if we made everyone work from home, using their own computers?  We could cut facility costs to almost $0! (I can't find it right now, but there was a storyline in the comedy webcomic "Greystone Inn" based on this concept...)

Comment: @Myles It already happens sometimes. My brother worked as an audit accountant for a while, and whenever they were onsite at a smaller company, they ended up being stuffed into a boardroom for a few weeks...

Comment: @Chronocidal, that is basically what I do. My rates are calculated so I can afford decent equipment, and it's significantly more fun to work on 40 threads and three monitors than on whatever the customer had lying around in storage.

Comment: @mbrig My site had a shortage of meeting rooms so even having one group like yours on site meant shuffling around regular and special meetings.  I remember due to bad timing at one point we had 3 separate groups on site using up our rooms which led to some tempers really flaring.

Comment: There are at least four answers I would like to accept at once, and I have appreciated all the answers here; I found it educational. So, etiquette demands I choose one, and this was the first (imho) that most completely answered the question. However the range of answers is the most useful aspect. I expect to refer to this question in future conversations at my company

Comment: My workplace recently switched to some sort of hot desking. It works quite well for us. My 7 person team is one desk short. The neighbouring 9 person team is also one desk short. I would assume the other teams have similar employee/desk ratios. And right next to where we sit is a pool of 4 desks shared among maybe 6 teams. So essentially, if you're early you can grab your preferred desk. If not, just grab any desk. If none available in "our" area, use a pool space. So far, the pool has always had open desks, because in reality, people work from home and call in sick every once in a while.

Comment: @PunkUnicorn One thing against hot desking that people think is "pro" When somebody use desk till 2 PM and somebody need to use desk from 2PM it won't be smooth switch. The call may need to be extended, you need to unplug, clean up then the second person need to set up. I've worked with such issue and we wasted around 1 hour a day waiting for that desk. AND we were required to clock in on our computers at certain time sharp.

Comment: I wouldn't describe your positive examples as examples of "hot desking" at all. In both cases, employees have desks reserved for them when they need it. In the first case, it's even for longer than a day. That doesn't have much to do with hotdesking for me.

Comment: @Myles "So if we take this to the logical conclusion... we are already paying employees to poop on company time, why not... no... guys... hear me out!"

Answer (score 153):

Hotdesking doesn't solve any problems, no matter whether the office is too small or not.

I've worked at a company that had 20-40% fewer seats than employees. Battles for chairs cost us (and company...) plenty of time. It was a drama. The most important part of the day was ensuring you had a chair.

Your company is probably expecting to grow. This could explain why they want to introduce the system now.

Or maybe they just want people to "network more". But that's not the way to achieve that.

Comment: If the company believes that many of their employees are out on call, remote, or occasional office visitors, then they might believe they are reducing the footprint of the office space, by having desks to accommodate the attending employees, without reserved desks to accommodate the unlikely to be present employees.  The problem is, at times when all hands meetings are held, you have too few desks under this plan for your employees.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, in the case of occasional office visitors, it's still better to have a few seats reserved for "occasional visitors" than make everybody fight for seats and take all their things with them every evening because some people aren't in the office most of the days.

Comment: I didn't have to read past "Hotdesking doesn't solve any problems" to agree. As good as the intentions might be for the company, I have yet to meet someone in person who found it a positive experience in the long run. Perhaps there are industries where there are more part-time workers where it actually does solve some problems?

Comment: "Battles for chairs cost us (and company...) plenty of time" - that's just bad management.  Hot desking can certainly resolve the problem of having less seats as long as there's a mechanism to report when people work from home to ensure that people who come in have a desk.

Comment: @UKMonkey: We had such a mechanism. But still, many people seem to decide in the morning whether they will come or not. Also, the company didn't calculate the number of seats we needed appropriately. There were simply not enough seats for everybody.

Comment: @Kozaky I didn't have to read past "Hotdesking doesn't solve any problems" to disagree and to think that this is a poor answer to a good-faith question specifically seeking to identify what problems it **does** solve.  It might introduce more issues than it solves and specific implementations might be a net negative for a company (as with this answerer's experience), but in my opinion this isn't a good Answer to the question.

Comment: Just make them all standing desks. Boom, chair problem solved.

Comment: Answers like these are what gets people to close questions as *opinion-based*. Please be specific: list things hot-desking might be expected to solve, and explain why it doesn't. Just stating a verdict is useless for helping people form an informed opionin.

Comment: @reinierpost: no, opinion-based questions make people write opinion-based answers. I've seen questions about advantages/ disadvantages, risks, red flags, closed on here.

Comment: @385703: they do, but IMO the problem is usually with the answers.

Comment: @WBT taking your line, the only answer to "what problems does it strive to solve" is "We have no idea what problems the guys who proposed it are striving to solve"  and to "does it actually solve these problems," "I would happily bet my own money that it won't, even when I don't know what it is intended to solve".

Comment: This seems more like a rant because you didn't perceive it as solving any problems at your place and it apparently was inadequately handled than a well founded answer.

Comment: This should not be the most upvoted answer to the question just because it's the first one in the default sort.

Comment: @WBT True, hence why I said I merely agreed rather than think this should be the correct answer, and too why I'm curious to see if there are examples of workplaces where it is of obvious benefit to employees as well as the company's wallet.

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked, and it disappoints me (though does not surprise me) that it's so highly upvoted.

Comment: So based on your personal experience of how many jobs where hot desking was standard in how many different industries can you decide that it cannot possibly work in all situations? What if we're talking about an international organization where the vast majority of employees work from home and only meet for specific scheduled meetings? Why would having 90% empty chairs all year round be an improvement in such a situation?

Comment: Although I agree it's not a good policy, saying it "doesn't solve any problems" because A) it has downsides, and B) it didn't work at your office, isn't a very sound answer. If you've got more detailed reasons as to why you think this, you might want to consider adding them to your answer.

Answer (score 104):

I am not a fan of the hot desk principle, but here are a few reason why people might be for it:

1. Tidier working area. If people can't keep their belongings at
   their desk, the desks are typically clutter free
2. Fresh perspective. Some people actually think differently when
   they are moved around. I don't, but I know people who claim where
   they sit affect them
3. Collaboration with new people. Depending on your field, this may
   encourage to work with more people than before and it could cause a
   rise in productivity

Again, I am not for hot desking; these are just reasons I have heard in the past.

Comment: 4. Smaller office space (eg 20% less chairs than people with the 20% working from home) requires hot desking.

Comment: @UKMonkey that is correct, but OP asked for reasons other than that

Comment: I agree totally with this one. I'd only also add that it can be useful for organisations spanning several offices when organising meetings if there aren't any dedicated meeting/board rooms in said office.

Comment: Re #1, that isn't solving a problem.  For many people, it's creating one.  If my desk isn't "cluttered", I am not working effectively.

Comment: @jamesqf depends who you ask. I know a lot of manager that would disagree. I personally keep a very messy desk (and I find it effective for me at least), but I know managers that would rather it be tidy and have used this to help with that

Comment: @SaggingRufus, what managers "want" and what is productive for individual employees are sometimes at odds...

Comment: @SaggingRufus:  But the purpose of managers is to hinder individual productivity.  See e.g. "The Peter Principle", or innumerable Dilbert cartoons :-)

Comment: +1 for #3 - if your work is done in dynamic teams that change from week to week or project to project, then being able to move and all sit together easily can be a big advantage for collaborating.  (The flip side to this is having to spend 20-60 minutes trying to track down that elusive person who's been procrastinating over giving you a critical update you need to finish your work!)

Comment: @SaggingRufus OP asked if it solves it... to which the answer is yes... in that it is the only method short on entire wfh policies that allows more people than desks.  Adding it to the list is just another way of saying "yes" imho.

Comment: @jamesqf `If my desk isn't "cluttered", I am not working effectively.` - we must differ with our definitions of "clutter" and/or "effective".

Comment: @ESR it probably depends on the work you are supposed to do. As a software developer I normally don't work with papers nor any equipment other than a computer. Therefore everything on my desk is just private stuff and a cup of coffee - it's there to build my zone and help me focus.

Comment: Disagree with the idea of tidier desks. You run into the tragedy of the commons. It's no one's responsibility, so clutter accumulates.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: As a software developer myself, I certainly do work with papers - and manuals, textbooks, &c.  It's often much easier to use them, even it the same material is available on-line (which it sometimes isn't).  But then work habits are an individual thing: just ask anyone who expects anything coherent from me before 10 AM at the earliest :-)

Comment: @RobCrawford Tragedy of the commons likely doesn't apply because an office is not an unregulated area. Company might establish rules that enforce cleaning up after one's done with work. Yes, this can start to feel like kindergarten. No, it's probably not going to make a comfy work environment for everybody.

Comment: @MauganRa And, at the point, the particularly good people get fed up and go elsewhere.  Making an unpleasant work environment in software development is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 27):

If some employees are not regularly at that office (e.g. mostly-remote workers), a hot desking system allows the desk space to be used more efficiently.  I believe this was the original reason for the system; it allows the company to save on office space that goes unused.  Also, if a worker has multiple office locations, s/he might not need a dedicated space at all of them; hot-desking can help accommodate.

When there is a consultant or consulting team coming in and regularly working at the client site, it is easier for them to work with the regular staff in a hot-desking arrangement, on the days when the consultants are in.

On days when there are several people out (e.g. popular times of the year to take holidays), the ones who are in can sit closer together for collaboration instead of feeling like the place is a ghost town.

If people are on teams that change relatively often, or on multiple teams, they can have the close desk proximity to one team while they are working with that team, and then easily change when working with a different team (e.g. a different day or a different week) without disruption of moving offices.

If people aren't allowed to keep things at the desk, it also makes for a tidier workspace and reduces the probability that an important paper will get buried under a mound of others on someone's desk.

Of course, hotdesking introduces new challenges such as the time cost of getting things set up every day and having to access a closet or cubby for the things one might otherwise keep in/at/on a desk.  However, forcing people to get up and walk around more might also reduce healthcare costs and associated loss in productivity from the health issues caused by long constant sitting.

If there aren't actually enough desks for the staff who show up on a given day, competition is likely to burn resources and staff are unlikely to have the space they need to be most effective.

Comment: If the company can afford cubbies and enough office space to accommodate them, why not instead spend the money on a desk for each employee and enough office space for *them*? And how is "forcing people to get up and walk around" a good thing, when they could use that energy more productively?

Comment: Walking around is probably only going to increase by a significant amount if company gets standing desks for everybody, or if everybody is forced to switch their desks after an hour.

Comment: It increases the probability that an important paper will wind up in the wastebasket, as opposed to under a mound of other papers.

Comment: @DavidThornley I don't think so.  People tend to take care of those things and pay attention to what they're throwing out, but consider safe on their desk to be taking care of something and then they don't notice when something gets buried.

Comment: @WBT It's easy to look at a piece of paper and misjudge its importance.  If you've got a pile and you don't know whether to keep something, you put it in the pile.  If you don't, you toss it at the end of the day.  I've had papers I thought unimportant turn out to be important.

Answer (score 22):

There are too many unknowns to answer your question. But, from experience, I can give a couple of examples where hot desking makes sense:

At my current place of employment, most departments don't use hot desking -- since most people work from the office. Except for our largest department: customer care. Customer care works 24/7/365, which many agents only working between 24 and 32 hours a week. We'd need a few more offices if everyone had their own desk.

I used to work for a company where its employees would spend most of their time at customers. Sometimes, I wouldn't be in the office for several months in a row. We did have a few desks to host people who would be in the office, but there weren't enough desks to seat everyone at the same time.

My spouse works at a place where everyone has a 3 or 4 day workweek. The office is small, and putting in enough desks for everyone would violate health and safety rules. Hot desking solves this problem.

Whether any of the situations described above apply to your company, I cannot deduce from your question.

Comment: yes at my last company the customer service desk was hot desked for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 17):

As others have already said, it solves little if any problems, but there is one situation that I have experienced where at least can be helpful.

That is the 24/7 business. Any business which has people in the offices 24/7, i.e. upto 3x8hr shifts. This is common in a call centre environment, but can also exist in other environments too, depending on the company.

I can't tell you if your company is thinking to use this or not, but it's an 'advantage' of hot desking - as long as you only ever have 1/3rd of your total workforce working, you only ever need desks for 1/3rd too.

Comment: Yes, this. It is even more useful if additionally the main work is not done at a desk. For example nurses in a hospital do not mainly work at desks, but they sometimes have paperwork to do. So hospitals provide them with desks, but only one or two per ward, which are used as needed, as it would obviously be silly (and impractical) to have a personal desk for each nurse who may ever work at the ward.

Answer (score 14):

**Hot desking is kind of the cloud service approach to office resource management**. Thus it fits similar scenarios and helps tackle similar challenges.

### Scenarios it fits

- there are limited office resources
- and there is substantial fluctuation in resource requirements, i.e. part-time workers, contractors, interns etc. that work at different times and/or switch projects a lot and/or are required to regularly switch the work place to do different tasks
- and/or close communication amongst workers is paramount

Examples would be, for example, companies that internally have a very heterogeneous work force with regard to working times and/or project associations or companies with a lot of sub-contractors, consultants, externals, that will occasionally visit their premises needing work spaces.

### Problems it solves

1. **Easy ad-hoc resource allocation**: Part-time worker coming in on Monday, give them one of the free desks, any desk will do. No cleaning required. No central management to assign desks required. Easy identification of a free resource (no one's sitting there/having his stuff there). 
   Same goes for external visitors that are at your building for a few meetings and that need a place to work in-between etc. This also helps for doing an ad-hoc short term project, no need for management to assign a new office just for this project, the respective people can just get free desks that are close-by.
2. **Easy resource re-allocation**: Worker A is ill and Worker B needs to fill his spot in team Alpha -> just use his place and be directly integrated with the team; Same goes if Worker A needs to support team Alpha for a week, just use any free place, if necessary Worker C who is currently working on a side project for team Alpha and thus doesn't need to sit *that* close this week can switch to another desk.
3. **Resource usage maximisation**: Considering the example where you have multiple contractors, instead of assigning each one office, which are both only used for half of the week, you assign them both one office which is used one half of the week by one and the other half by the other contractor. Or maybe by some guys from each contractor each day of the week.
4. **Pipelining**: You can easy build a pipeline where the rooms/workplaces instead of the workers change; thus one worker can guide one product/customer throughout a process. Consider a car service, where the technician first does the paper work at a desk, then goes to the garage with you, then fills out the report at another desk.
5. **High information exchange rate**: As workers can easily decide where to sit and change whom they sit next to, it facilitates a high rate of communication between individual workers.
6. **Resilience**: if one resource fails, i.e. a desk/building/room is unavailable, it is easy to switch that worker to another desk.
7. **Cleanliness**: As with most things standardized (proper standard), it is easier for others to use your resources, i.e. the cleaning personal will find it way easier to properly clean your desk regularly. People with a focus on everything being clean and orderly might also find this to be a psychological advantage.

### Challenges it introduces

- Your workers need to be able to run on cloud infrastructure, i.e. they need to clear their desk each evening and take everything they require to work with them
- Workers may not "settle in" long-term by choosing their preferred seating place (next to window, flowers, quiet corner) and keep it for their time at the company; this can for some workers make it harder to be creative or get into "the flow"
- Workers that require special equipment at their desk have particularly increased setup effort or may need to be excempted from hot desking. This applies to workers that perform special tasks, but also to workers with disabilities, requiring special desks or chairs
- You need to provide core infrastructure that makes it easy for workers to find free places that fit their requirements (e.g. close to other members of team X)
- You incur overhead to setup and coordination, i.e. get your place ready to start working and find other workers you need to communicate with
- It's more difficult to estimate how many places you need (where)
- Workers may need to be more independent and figure out who is best sitting where in their office by themselves

### Opinionated Summary

The crux with this is, that your workers need to buy into the concept. Especially if you apply it to everyone, not all might see the benefit as they don't fall into the groups of people that gain anything by using this approach. I guess this is why this question generates a highly upvoted opinionated dismissive answer; people fearing they need to adapt this, when it doesn't fit their working style. It is also easy to mess it up, same as with cloud infrastructure, management may only see the potential cost benefit of reducing the number of desks - and underestimate the actual requirements in terms of number of desks or the impact of a single day where there are a couple places missing. While it is often seen as management imposing on workers, it can also be an empowerment, as it fits well with a bottom-up approach, where workers manage themselves (to some degree), e.g. just decide to sit together with whomever they need to work with for their current task.

Generally speaking, I've seen this work well, when it was sensibly combined with a traditional approach. Part-time workers, internals, and workers that switch projects on a regular basis go full hot-desking, while workers that do normal day-jobs all through the week have allocated desks and only clear them out when going for an external project or having holidays of a week or longer. 
Sometimes there are also dedicated hot-desking rooms to use *in addition* to normal offices, for ad-hoc group projects.

An important lesson is also: Depending on what you do hot-desking for, you might not actually reduce the number of desks, e.g. if you provide separate hot-desk rooms for ad-hoc projects in addition to your "normal" offices (hot-desk or not).

And yes, if applied blindly to force a mostly 9-5 workforce to use hot-desking, it will likely bring more problems than solve things.

(Then again, it's successfully applied in almost all schools which combines resource maximisation and pipelining.)

Comment: This is a very good summary, but one challenge I would add is productivity. Most creative work requires the ability to concentrate, and that's more difficult to do with frequent distractions. Hot-desks remove the ability to control the work environment. The creative worker might get the "good desk" in the quieter area with fewer visual distractions on one day, but the next day they could get a "bad desk" in the noisiest, busiest location. A pragmatic workspace should ensure key contributors always have quiet workspaces without distractions (and without cost of daily setup/cleanup time).

Comment: @RandyHill I agree that it makes it harder to "settle into a comfort zone place", be that a quiet place or one close to flowers etc. But the environment it's suited for is typically one that prioritizes communication and likely the ability to switch tasks quickly, which might also be a negative indicator for people who like to "settle in" and solve big issues by deep thought. I'll see if I can integrate that later. Thx for the comment.

Comment: Additionally, it causes challenges in inclusivity, disability-related and other health-based adjustments, etc.

If someone has specific needs (eg. they need a specific chair because of the kind of support it gives, the desk/monitor to be at a certain height, to use a trackball rather than a mouse, for example (not an exhaustive list by any stretch of the imagination) then if you do true hotdesking, you either have to have all these adjustments set up for the user at the start of every shift they do (and undone at the end ) or you have to assign them a specific permanently free desk

Answer (score 9):

> Employees in such workplaces use existing offices **only occasionally or for short periods of time**, which leaves offices vacant.

Pulled right from your wikipedia page. I think this is important as "hot desking" is meant for workers to share the same desk, but at *different* times. Like maybe a call center job or something.

I think it's important to know when you'll be in the office and when the next person will be in the office. I'd hope your company would schedule different time slots for each of the desks rather than having everyone fight for space.

I believe it comes down to saving money and resources. They'd only have to manage one workstation and just your account rather than managing multiple workstations.

I think it's important depending on what industry you're in. Are you a call center? Or traditional office? Hard to determine from your question.

Comment: IF you have multiple shifts, AND nobody ever works over their allocated shift, it can work. If anyone works late, or turns up early, they disrupt the system.

Comment: @AlanCampbell Not if you properly plan some buffer spaces. Saw it working very well in a company with a substantial amount of part time workers and a substantial chance of regular workers doing a home office day.

Comment: @AlanCampbell Right, the objective isn't to make work convenient for the workers, but allow the company to save money and resources.

Answer (score 8):

There is another case to consider, layoffs. This does not seem to be a problem at your company, as there are enough desks for employees. But consider one where 100% of desks are utilized and there is 20% spillover into conference rooms and such at times. A reduction in staff will be less noticed by existing employees as all desks are already over-allocated. 
This also helps by de-personalizing space. That desk is where "John" a loyal employee of 20years used to work. So no stigma associated with certain spaces(cursed desk), and no nostalgic remembrance.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The sentence in your quote claims otherwise, so I'm not sure what you're replying to. No. paulj was saying they'd be _less_ noticed, not that they'd be *un*noticed.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Or you just didn't notice the layoffs that you didn't notice? Either way, "I noticed every layoff" isn't a valid argument against "sometimes layoffs might not be noticed". Maybe _you_ will notice every layoff ever, even the people you've never interacted with and don't know exist, at your company. But other people might not. And other people might have less chance of noticing it if the desks are constantly being shuffled.

Comment: In many locales the management has to announce layoffs, even to people not affected. So not only do you notice you will get notified of it.

Comment: And they are also mandated by law to announce (not to mention being highlighted in the media) how many were affected. It's impossible to have "quiet" layoffs.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Yes. They are announced. But it the person who sat next to you for 20years who is now gone...that feeling is not noticed because it was never there.

Comment: This is very twisted logic that I can't ever see actually being true.  Any time I've been at a company that's had layoffs, it's the #1 topic of conversation among employees.  There's no such thing as a 'less noticed' layoff.

Comment: @Paulj if they fire enough ppl nobody will know that guy was there for 20 years. this is a silly answer

Comment: @17of26 I'm sorry if you are unable to understand the different feelings and emotions when coming into an office where half the desks are now empty vs not. That feeling and that feeling alone.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your management. They're the ones that implemented it.

Start with your boss.  Tell her what you told us.

"Kate, I see that when we move to the new office we're going to be doing hot desking.  The new location will be large enough to accommodate the company size; there will be enough desks for everyone, space is not a problem.  Do you know what's behind this decision?"

Comment: The question asks what problems hot-desking solve, so this seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling No, the question asks what problems it STRIVES to solve, not what problems it solves. The only people who can answer that are those who proposed introducing it. The number of problems it ACTUALLY solves is zero.

Comment: @alephzero That part of the question is not specifically about their situation (the opposite, in fact, if you look at the post history), and should thus be answerable by other people.

Answer (score 5):

Hotdesking solves the problem of having a happy workforce who can come in to work every day to a familiar, comfortable environment and get down to productive pursuits aided by the dependability of a consistent routine. Thank goodness!

Honestly, it might seem petty, but I'd be out — I rely on a routine and a predictable work environment and the instigation of hotdesking would entirely throw me off my game, for no benefit.

Comment: there are literally answers here that answer why it is needed and works - check out abigail's  answer. the question isn't "how would you handle hotdesking"

Comment: Not to mention the fact that our customized workspaces (keyboards, mice and HD monitors) are no longer available.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Right! Headphones. Notebooks. Desk drawers with our favourite teabags. Pictures of our kids and so forth. How clinical to start from scratch every day.

Answer (score 4):

While I generally agree with [385703's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/121712/what-other-problems-does-hot-desking-solve/121714#121714) in that hotdesking generally causes more problems than it solves, its use in the business really depends on the nature of the work and office culture.

For example, in a company that promotes work from home you may find that this is used to optimise the use of space and can even dictate corporate real estate policy to ensure that space is fully utilised. This can backfire if smart working isn't adopted to the same extent as expected or if particular locations become more popular than others.

Where hotdesking is used in larger organisations where projects can span multiple offices. Here hotdesking can provide access to space on an ad hoc basic and minimises the amount of time that desks are left empty. I have also seen organisations designate small hotdesk areas to particular projects to allow teams to sit and work together even when hotdesking without taking up more desks than strictly necessary.

In the same vein, some offices may be client facing, and particularly in areas where real estate is limited and expensive (think London for the UK or other central city hubs) hotdesking can be valuable to enable multiple projects to utilise this space on a scheduled basis - much in the same way as a meeting room booking service can be used.

In your case it's difficult to make a judgement without understanding more about the office culture/practices but it seems likely that 385703's suggestion that the company is expecting to expand could be the case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem hot-desking is trying to solve is **exactly** "not having enough desks". I used to work for a consulting company where I would spend 95% of time at the customers' and maybe 5% at the office. The office could only accommodate maybe 20% of all consultants, but there was never a shortage of seats so hot desking totally made sense.

Another use case for hot-desking is when a significant share of employees wear several hats at a time. If 100 people spend 50% of their time at the office and another 50% of time in a lab, it's tempting to organize 50 office desks and 50 lab desks instead of 100. The downside is that sometimes a most of people have to do the same kind of work (end-of-year reports and such) and suddenly half of the employees have to do office work at the lab with poor Internet and no printers.

Employers who claim that hot-desking is introduced to solve a different problem than the lack of desks are usually hiding unpopular reasons (saving costs at the expense of worse working conditions) under cool slogans about team cohesion and agility.

Comment: An effect of this is to discourage consultants from spending too much time at the home office, when they could be out at the client site and billing. Obviously, this is something management would want to encourage.

Answer (score 2):

Proponents of hot-desking (who usually prefer other terms like "unassigned seating") often argue that it encourages collaboration/networking within the organisation. For instance, [this blog post](http://blog.turningart.com/flexible-workspaces-what-they-are-and-why-you-need-them) says:

> An article around workplace design in the Harvard Business Review
>   collected performance data ... and found that “face-to-face
>   interactions are by far the most important activity in an office.”
>   Moreover, their data suggests that creating chance encounters and
>   unplanned interactions, a design concept Steve Jobs pioneered at
>   Pixar, improves performance. By instituting unassigned desks and
>   communal work areas, employees are more likely to move throughout the
>   day, which facilitates interaction and collaboration between employees
>   who might have minimal interaction otherwise.

However, this isn't an entirely accurate characterisation of [the HBR article that it cites](https://hbr.org/2014/10/workspaces-that-move-people). That article notes that different solutions work for different workplaces, and discusses a case study where hot-desking gave very poor results:

> Companies must have an understanding of what they’re trying to achieve
>   (higher productivity? more creativity?) before changing a space. For
>   example, what worked at the pharma company didn’t work at a large
>   furniture manufacturer that transformed its headquarters from classic
>   cubicles to an open-plan office in which approximately 60% of the
>   workforce had unassigned seating ... The company had hypothesized that
>   fewer desks and a smaller footprint would move people closer together,
>   increasing the likelihood of interaction. Unassigned seating would
>   make interaction between people in different groups more likely. Such
>   interaction did increase, by 17%—but energy levels (the number of
>   individuals’ encounters during the day) dropped by an average of 14%.
>   This suggests that the space simply reshuffled stationary workers
>   rather than creating movement. Someone from marketing might bump into
>   new people because their temporary desks happened to be close by, but
>   none of them were leaving their workstations once they got there. **As a
>   result, team communication dropped by 45%. The company saved money on
>   space by reducing the number of fixed workstations, but both revenue
>   and productivity plummeted.**

My workplace moved to hot-desking a couple of years back. Although this kind of unplanned interaction was mentioned as one of the benefits, I don't think it's substantially increased. People tend to prefer sitting in a familiar place, so most of us now alternate between two or three standard locations. Moreover, because accommodation is coordinated at workgroup level, each workgroup ends up with its own "home zone" so even though we shuffle round a bit, we're still sitting with the same people.

One complication here is that we moved to about 30% teleworking at the same time as we adopted hot-desking, and obviously teleworking reduces unplanned interactions.

Comment: Every time I hear "it will increase communication and collaboration" the result is the opposite, with the added effect of reducing the ability to concentrate. Open plan offices, hot-desking, whatever -- they're always promoted in terms of teamwork, but that never pans out.

Answer (score 2):

I work in an office which uses hotdesks.

My office is a services company where most of the people will be working on client location. People comes to office when there is no project assigned to them or they have to work in non client work.

This works well, as the other scenario where each employee is assigned a fixed work place will cause huge waste of space.

The same company's office in another country where majority works from office doesn't have hot desk policy and is assigned a fixed desk.

TL;DR. It only works well for companies where a significant percentage of employees work remotely.

Answer (score 1):

If the company offers different areas, it might help you to get the right environment. Their could be quiet places where any noise should be avoided, like in a library. Other areas could allow some talk. In meeting rooms, phone booths, collaboration rooms (which cannot be booked in advance) distractions to others can be avoided.
Depending on the work you have to do, you choose your place. If you have to concentrate for a longer time, go to the quiet places. If you have to talk to other team members, go to somewhere else. If you have a phone call or a spontaneous discussion with two co-workers, choose the phone booth or a collaboration room.

Answer (score -1):

> What problems does hot desking strive to solve, apart from not having
>   enough desks?

Management inferiority complex. Also, consultants need of a new car.

Many of these projects are buzzword bingo bullshit dreamed up by some consulting company after a short study of the workplace environment, and those profits only need to last (or seem to last) until the manager is promoted to his next position and the same consulting company can come back in with a new plan.

There are, of course, circumstances in which sharing desks is appropriate, as outlined by, e.g. Dmitry in his answer.

In a regular office setting, however, hot-desking is one of those consulting non-solutions. I've worked as a consultant, we always had one eye out for the follow-up business. No solution was ever intended to be permanent.